# Python pandas pivot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below.

```
   id  A  B  C
0   1  1  1  1
1   1  5  7  2
2   2  6  9  3
3   3  1  5  4
4   3  4  6  2
```

After evaluating conditions,

```
   id  A  B  C  a_greater_than_b  b_greater_than_c  c_greater_than_a
0   1  1  1  1             False             False             False
1   1  5  7  2             False              True             False
2   2  6  9  3             False              True             False
3   3  1  5  4             False              True              True
4   3  4  6  2             False              True             False
```

And after evaluating conditions, want to aggregate the results per id.

```
id  a_greater_than_b  b_greater_than_c  c_greater_than_a
1   False             False             False
2   False             True              False
3   False             True              False
```

Comment: what about color yellow? Also is this related to the previous question you asked?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not fully clear, but you can combine [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and aggregation per group (here I am assuming the `min` as your example showed that 1/1/0 -> 0 and 1/1/1 -> 1, but you can use other logics, e.g. `last` if you want to get the last row per group after sorting by date):

```
out = (pd
   .get_dummies(df[['color', 'size']])
   .groupby(df['id'])
   .min()
 )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    color_blue  color_yellow  size_l
id                                  
A1           0             0       1
```